# Get data from MYSQL from two days ago

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I am trying to get a row count on the number of entries in my database from two days ago.  I have the code below which gets the data from now until two days ago, but i just want the data of all of the entries in the database from midnight to midnight two days ago.

This is the code i have to get from now until two days ago.

```
 SELECT * FROM vistordetails1 WHERE date_time >= ( NOW() - INTERVAL 2880 MINUTE )
```

could I do something like this

```
SELECT * FROM vistordetails1 WHERE date_time >= ( INTERVAL 1440 MINUTE - INTERVAL 2880 MINUTE )
```

Comment: why INTERVAL MINUTE and not DAY ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Close, give this a shot...

```
SELECT * FROM vistordetails1 
WHERE date_time <= ( NOW() - INTERVAL 1440 MINUTE ) 
  AND date_time >= ( NOW() - INTERVAL 2880 MINUTE )
```

SQL can be a bit confusing at times. Try to think of this in a programming construct. You want to do something if your value is withen a certain range.

```
if(val > 1 && val < 10){
  //value is between 1 and 10 exclusive
}else{
  //value is out side the range
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
  FROM visitordetails1
WHERE date_time BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 DAY) 
                    AND DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 DAY)
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/97616/1)**

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `date()` function to get rid of the time component:

```
SELECT *
FROM vistordetails1
WHERE date_time >= ( date(NOW()) - INTERVAL 2880 MINUTE ) and
      date_time < date(now())
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want items between two dates, you need to set both a minimum and maximum:

```
SELECT * FROM vistordetails1 WHERE date_time >= (NOW() - INTERVAL 2880 MINUTE) AND date_time <=  (NOW() - INTERVAL 1440 MINUTE)
```

Answer (score 0):

No, that would actually select entries from 1 day after the start of time (1. Jan. 1970). Try this statement:

```
SELECT * FROM vistordetails1 
    WHERE date_time <= ( NOW() - INTERVAL 1440 MINUTE ) 
    AND date_time >= ( NOW() - INTERVAL 2880 MINUTE )
```

Comment: Also have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7756832/1553481) for a more elegant, slightly different way.

Answer (score 0):

This will consider 2 full days:

```
select date(now()) as today, date_add(date(now()), interval -2 day) "2 days ago";
```

I am using the function date to illustrate to you how to get the date part of a complete date time. Adapt to your needs and you will get there.