# Output last x amount of saved datatables from sql from saved timestamp

Tags: php, sql

I have a datatable that saves created data as : user.createddate

Every time I add to the datatable, it saves as such for this data(timestamp) :

2016-02-02 09:10:26

What would be the best way for me to parse the timestamp, and only display results that are "x" old?

I added the following per suggestion, but it still does not parse correctly :

```
$cond = 'WHERE user.createddate >= DATEADD(day,-7, GETDATE())';
```

@Eugen helped me out in the comments.  Basically, user.createddate has the entire datetime that needs to be seperated first to give me an approximation to work with in days previous, using the following code you can do as such :

```
$sql = "SELECT 
                * 
            FROM 
                ".$table." 
            WHERE 
                DATE(edit_date) = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
            ";  
    return $sql;
```

I will mark you as best answer, if you post as actual answer.  Thanks!

Comment: field type 'int(11)' , value 'unix timestamp'  :-)

Comment: I already have it saving the data as it is needed, how would I display the most recent database additions within the selected timeframe?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM <TABLE>
       WHERE date >= ‘firstdate’ AND date < ‘seconddate’`

Comment: that would work perfect, but it would have to be something like this :
WHERE user.createddate >= 5daysprevious of currentdatetime

Comment: look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7756708/mysql-select-rows-from-exactly-7-days-ago

Comment: PERFECT, THANKS!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Use MySQL functions: **NOW**, **DATE_SUB** and **INTERVALL**

```
user.createddate BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND NOW()
```

Answer (score -1):

use this line :
this work correctly :)
 echo time_elapsed_string('2016-02-02 09:10:26');